# Virtuemart get the shipping and handling costs from where?

Tags: virtuemart

This might be a long shot, but I am trying to find what global variable holds the shipping and handling amount in virtuemart?

I see it is set using $shipping_display, but whenever I run a var_export($shipping_display) is NULL. However, if i make an order, it is showing on the page...

Any thoughts?!

Comment: Have you set your shipping prices in the Virtuemart backend? Or are you trying to modify the shipping price from the core files/your own plugin?

Comment: Trying to modify the core. It is setup correct via the core virtuemart idea, I just want to be able to calculate the Total differently. I want to half the shipping with a 50/50 payment plan I have. Currently, you have to pay the whole shipping...